# Can I solve Silverlight color rendering differences in IE7/8?

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, firefox, rendering

I have a Silverlight control that tries to have the same background as the underlaying div, but I'm facing color difference problems in IE7/8:

[image: IE7/8]

That doesn't seems to be a problem for Firefox.

[image: FF]

Does anyone has a tip how to solve this problem? I try to avoid using the windowless mode in Silverlight and alpha transparency as 1st) it's slower and 2nd) shows a bounding select box when you click in the control in Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately I managed to solve the problem. Seems that it's a gamma correction problem. The PNG file allows you to set gamma correction information and Silverlight and IE seems to handle it differently.

[This](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/png-gamma/) page explains the problem and saved the day. [This](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) tool as also necessary to remove the gamma information from the PNG.

Hopefully this information will be useful for someone.